# How can I track UI events on Instruments

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instruments

I am developing an iPhone app, and I would like to see the events that are fired inside of it, for example when a tap on the screen was made, I would like to see the event fired inside instruments and learn how the objects are communicating with each other.
I tried to use Instruments to catch events using the cocoa events and it yielded nothing. The process was my app. I am not sure which profiling tool can show me what I need.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tap into the event system, you can create a custom subclass of `UIWindow` and override the `sendEvent:` method. Then you can use the Xcode debugger to examine the event object. I've used this in the past to log things like touch events.

It's not possible to do this kind of thing using the Instruments tool.